# Can we support internal "chrome://" URLs?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, hyperlinks

Is it possible that we could support the internal `chrome://` URLs used by Google Chrome and Chromium? There are many questions where one has to access an internal page used by Chrome to solve the problem. For example.

1. [Why is chrome://settings and chrome://plugins broken?](https://superuser.com/q/337748/137430)
2. [Is there an "about:config" (Firefox) In Google's Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/23662/137430)
3. [How do I install a crx file on Google Chrome Dev?](https://superuser.com/q/431977/137430)

While this is a minor annoyance, it is still frustrating every time I happen to encounter it. Plus, there's no harm in allowing it so why prevent it?

*By the way, can we also support the `about:` style links used by Firefox?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only [whitelisted and supported URI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71108/links-with-uris-of-schemes-other-than-http-https-are-broken) protocols are **http**, **https** and **ftp**.

All other link protocols go through the Markdown sanitising wash and removed.

Besides, you [can't click those links anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97413/chrome-link-does-not-show-up-as-a-link).

Comment: I'm reading that other post (thanks for finding it, search on SE sucks =/), but what was Code Grey's security concerns?

Comment: Create an HTML page on your machine with such a link. And then try and click on it. See where it takes you.

Comment: Ah. So the reason is that Google Chrome actually doesn't follow `chrome://` links?

Comment: That's the security concern. Google Chrome won't let you get yourself in trouble by clicking on such links where it hasn't generated them itself

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering a duplicate. =P I just couldn't find it via SE or Google.